# Dynamically show or hide div based on a javascript function return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstl

I am handling user management module where particular parts of web page have permissions to assigned users. So, I have to check if the logged in user has access to div or not based on the div id.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h4> I want to: </h4>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
       href="#"
       id="dropdownMenuLink"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       aria-haspopup="true"
       aria-expanded="false">  
        Select the action and get information
    </a>
</div>
```

As i have several divs on each page , it is not viable to query for the element and then set the display style using jquery.

So, my requirement is to call a java script function which returns a Boolean value based on which a div can be displayed or not displayed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to just only hide some elements from users without permissions. You shoud rather solve the issue at server-side, and not to load permission-requiring stuff to browser at all, if a user doesn't have rights to see it. It is far too easy to show the hidden elements with the browser's dev tools.

Comment: As @Teemu said hiding it won't prevent the user from seeing it! Just opening the console and override the style will make him see it. If it's something very important it should never be sent to client side in the first place!

Comment: Basically its not to just hide, load that section of the condition is not met kind of.